# Basic intuition for motor torque

Tags: motors, torque

when shopping on digi-key or other electronics distributor, I can see the Torque - Holding spec, given in oz-in and mNm.

I understand Nm in a torque context when the force is applied as a lever at a distance from the rotation point (for instance when applying 1 N force on a wrench, 20 cm from the rotational point, would give 0,2Nm).

But what does it mean when we are talking about motor torque? It seems to me that it is like opposite: the motor is applying force at the rotational point, so the distance is always 0.

Does it mean motor specs are always measuring the force the motor is applying 1 meter away from it? I am trying to have a good intuition of what Nm mean when looking at motors, because tutorials online only talk about wrenches or other cases when the force is applied **away** from the ration point.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would you calculate the torque if there was a gear of diameter 5cm on the end of the shaft?

Comment: G=10 (close enough :-) ). Work in kg.m say 100 Nm = 10 kgm. Visualise a 10 kg mass on a 1 marm. You can se the effects of the torque by the bend in a suitable dimentioned arm and measure it with load clls on the arm - or by the ability to make a clamp at the hub slip or ... numberous ways. 

If you now twist that arm rotationally on a plane at right angles to gravity you will again induce a bend or measured strain or slippage. The same effect results from the same torque. A useful approximation is watts = kg.m x RPM. ie power = torque x rotational speed. ... .

Comment: ...  The above is derived from: "power = force x distance per second" and the units just happen to cancel nicely. |Summary - torque is "twisting power" It doesn't matter how you produce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a motor with torque rating of 10 Nm  and it came in a box with just a shaft.

The rating just means if you attach a pulley with R =1 meters you get ten Nm torque. But if you attach a 0.2 meters pulley you get 5*10=50 Nm torque. Of course your belt runs 5 times slower.

Shaft torque/ demand torque = radius of your pulley in meters.

Comment: Thank you! but what if I decide to install a load directly on the motor shaft? How can I tell the amount of work my motor can do? Do I use the rotor radius instead? for example: I found a stepper with 230mNm and has a radius of 2cm. does it mean I would get 230/50 so less than 5 Nm?

Comment: 230 x50= 11500mNm available torque.